# jQuery blueimp File Upload won't delete over ssl

Tags: jquery, file-upload, ssl, blueimp

I am using the plugin found here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I initialize it like so:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    formData: {task: taskId},
    url: '/file'
});
```

It seems that everything works except deletion.  When I try to delete a file, the request goes over HTTP instead of HTTPS even though the entire site uses SSL.

**Update**:

It looks like whenever a file is loaded as an "existing" file (either when the plugin is initialized or a file is successfully uploaded), the delete button for that row is has an attribute called `data-url` that has "http://" in it like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="DELETE" data-url="http://mysite.com/file?file=test.pdf&amp;hash=cd8d4d2dd2a9028cfc533b70b05f70329c288500">
    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
    <span>Delete</span>
</button>
```

Anybody know where this gets loaded from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it server side, where your delete url is specified.

Comment: That was it.  Totally forgot to check what the script was passing back.